# pam_tally2 not locking user out after failed attempts on Ubuntu 14 and 16

Tags: pam

I'm not sure if this issue is with `pam_tally2` itself or with Ubuntu which is what I'm trying to find out.  `pam_tally2` for some reason is having issues on 14 and 16.  My `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` file looks as follows:

```
auth      required      pam_env.so
auth      required      pam_tally2.so deny=5 unlock_time=900 onerr=fail
auth      [success=1 default=ignore]   pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth      requisite     pam_deny.so
auth      required      pam_permit.so 
auth      optional      pam_cap.so
```

The first two lines I inserted manually based on previous forums and the man page.  (For testing purposes I changed `deny` to `=3` and `unlock_time` to `=20` so as not to take so long testing).

1. After doing so, nothing seems to take effect until I reboot the machine which is unlike pam where usually changes to pam take effect immediately.
2. After rebooting and intentionally failing password input 3 times I am successfully locked out for 20 seconds however I notice the counter says I failed 4 times even though it's only 3.  Also taking note, when inputting the wrong password, the usual message displayed is `Invalid password, please try again`, in red text and once the system is locked out, the message `Account locked due to 4 failed logins, appears in white text`.
3. After waiting 20 seconds and inputting the correct password, it still fails me one more time before changing the fail text to the original red text but then unlocking after I put the password in correctly yet again.  Furthermore, the account lockout only seems to work on the first login after the system reboot.  If I login correctly that once or intentionally fail logging in, afterwards, I will be able to login no matter how many times I fail.

Some forums and blogs say that you also need to put:

```
account     required     pam_tally2.so
```

inside the `common-account` file also

Other forums say to put the the aforementioned line but with all the options that you put in the `common-auth` file too.  Neither of these approaches seem to make pam_tally2 work.

I've also tried experimentally to put

```
account     required     pam_env.so
```

inside the `common-account` file as the first line.  This doesn't seem to work or change anything either.

I've tried putting the `pam_env.so` line above and below the `pam_tally2.so` in both files in all possible combinations and this doesn't seem to correct the behavior.

If anyone knows why `pam_tally2.so` isn't working or if it's a bug with Ubuntu please let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have been dealing with similar issues on 16.04 to get this all working. Many answers online are incorrect or incomplete. Here is a link to a good and correct explanation. (https://linux-audit.com/locking-users-after-failed-login-attempts-with-pam_tally2/) I have the lockout working correctly except for the lock screen does not increment the tally. The lock screen is controlled by gnome-screensaver, where the login/switch user screen is controlled by lightdm. Your issue may be similar where the first time after a reboot you are using lightdm, and later attempts are using the lock screen.

Answer (score 1):

see [Ubuntu_16.04](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=pam_tally)
you need also add line `account required pam_tally2.so` to `/etc/pam.d/common-account`

Answer (score 0):

I had same experience. And I solve it as below.

1. vim [/etc/pam.d/**login**]
   not the [/etc/pam.d/common-auth]
2. Add the following lines.
   **auth required pam_tally2.so deny=4 even_deny_root unlock_time=1200**

   - deny=4 (lock the account after 4 failed logins)
   - even_deny_root (Root account will be locked as well)
   - unlock_time=1200 (unlocked after 20 minutes)
3. Reference

   - My Ubuntu : Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
   - Command : man pam_tally2

Comment: Hi.  Where in the /etc/pam.d/login file do you put this line?  Order is very important in pam and you can't just put it anywhere.  Also, in my login file I have the following line:
@include common-auth
which is an import line that imports my contents from the common-auth file so essentially those contents are already in /etc/pam.d/login